# Log In/Registration PHP Object Oriented style error

Tags: php

I'm new to Object-Oriented in PHP I'm trying to put a login and registration form into my social media site project. And I encounter this error `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in [DIRECTORY]/user.php:11` which is this (the whole code of user.php):

```
<?php
    include_once 'lib/database_config.php';

    class User {
        public $db;

        public function reg_user($name, $userName, $userPassword, $email) {
            $userPassword = md5($userPassword);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$userName' OR email='$email'";

            // the error line                 
            $check = $this->db->query($sql);
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            $count_row = $check->num_rows;

            if($count_row == 0) {
                $sql1 = "INSERT INTO users SET username='$userName', password='$userPassword', fullName='$name', email='$email'";
                $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql1) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data can't insert.");
                return $result;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Login Process
        public function check_login($emailusername, $password) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql2 = "SELECT id from users WHERE email='$emailusername' or username='$emailusername' and password='$password'";

            // Check if the username is available in the table 
            $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql2);
            $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $count_row = $result->num_rows;

            if($count_row == 1) {
                $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $user_data['id'];
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Session start
        public function get_session() {
            return $_SESSION['login'];
        }

        public function user_logout() {
            $_SESSION['login'] = FALSE;
            session_destroy();
        }
    }


?>
```

The purpose of the above code is mainly for all the functionality of login and registration form (there are some function code blocks in other files.) but I think the problem is around the user.php(this one) & I think it's lacking of something that I've been figuring out for an hour.

Comment: You're not going live with this are you? MD5 is old and broken. Use `password_hash()` instead. You're also open to injection; use a prepared statement.

Comment: Where exactly are you assigning a value to `$this->db`?  I would expect this to be perhaps in a constructor, but you don't have one.

Comment: Nope not going live, it's just a test to a local machine. And yes I know password_hash() it's easy, short & more secure but since this is a local machine only testing... I use MD5. 

Comment: Can you share the 'lib/database_config.php' file

Comment: Protect your input against SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

you are calling $this->db->query($sql);

But at no time did you assign value to the $this->**db** variable

Comment: Turns out that's the problem, solved it! In my lib/database_config.php, there's the value for the $db and then I kinda misplaced it but now it works. A slightly stupid error in my end.

Comment: @Potato-Developer you should accept this as answer then.